# Import Data from Microsoft Access

Tags: php, ms-access, import

The system I'm building is attempting to read Microsoft Access DBs from a different system. I essentially need to be able to read the data, parse it, and do something with it. If I could somehow load it into an associative array, a database, or anything else, that'd be great.

Our users will have to import these files themselves, so we can't ask for preconversion into something else.

I've tried looking on SO and Google but haven't found *anything* close to what I'm talking about.

Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Jet/ACE is not a server database engine -- it's file-based, and the machine you're running the code on needs SMB networking access to the MDB/ACCDB you're opening.

Comment: What's Jet/ACE? What's ACCDB?

Comment: Jet/ACE is the database engine you're using, though you may be using only Jet 4 (the de facto Jet 5 was renamed ACE). ACCDB is the new file format for the ACE. Both ACE and ACCDB were introduced with Access 2007. If you're using Jet 4, then ignore the ACE and ACCDB parts of my comment. If you don't know then perhaps you should give it up entirely.

Comment: This is a ".db" file and can be read by Access 2000 -- this is a very, very old file. I'm starting to think it might be Sybase or something else -- and any idea to give up on anything, is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [ODBC](http://no.php.net/manual/en/intro.uodbc.php) extension can do the job.

Comment: For anyone else reading this -- per my question, this was the correct answer. What didn't know was that it was a Paradox database, and PHP provides a paradox_db class that can be used which was my solution.